# How to catch a hashmap in POST of a REST handle using Apache Jersey

Tags: rest, post, jersey

I wish to catch an XML (HashMap) of this format in my POST handler

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <labels>
      <label>label1</label>
      <label>label2</label>
      ...
    </labels>
  <entry>
  ...
<entries>
```

I wish my POST handler using Apache Jersey to look like this

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void createEntries(@MagicAnnotation HashMap<id, List<label>> entryMap){
    }
```

What is the closest I can get to this?

I am open to a better representation of a HashMap to XML. I just don't wish to parse xml manually and want to catch equivalent JSON as well.
I am not sure if some JAXBElement can be used instead of jersey annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not supposed to access the POST body this way.
You have to define several classes to let Jersey parse the XML response.

Your code will look like:

```
@POST
public Response post(Entries entries) {
  Storage.put(entries);
  return Response.ok().build();
}
```

To make this work Entries have to be JAXB compatible:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Entries {
  @XmlElement List<Entry> entries;
}

@XmlType
public class Entry {
  @XmlAttribute String id;
  @XmlElement Labels labels;
}

@XmlType
public class Labels {
  @XmlElement List<String> label;
}
```

*Ah, and Jersey is not from Apache but from Sun.*